# Water physics not rendering

Tags: rendering, physics, fluid-simulation

I think I have all objects and physics checked for rendering but my water simulation is not rendering. Can somebody please explain what is wrong?. Adding my file.

This is my water simulation [image]

This is my final render
[image]

Here is my file.
https://pasteall.org/blend/5c3b35746037404191b2bd7c5b7074f3

Comment: What is the domain material? What kind of cache are you using? (Will view the blend file when I can: I am on mobile right now)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Select your domain and check "show emitter", then it will be rendered.

[image]

Comment: You guys are the best. Problem solved. Thank you very much.

Comment: Thank you. Glad I could help.